# Equation of hyperbola after rotation of $45$ degrees

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't help but lose it...all I'm missing is where my negative is wrong!!

I want to rotate the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=2$ by $45$ degrees and show this equals $y=\frac1{x}$.

So I applied the rotation matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos{45}&-\sin{45}\\\sin{45}&\cos{45}\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ and get an $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$ where
$$x'=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-y)$$
$$y'=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x+y)$$
Plugging this into my hyperbola gives me
$$\left[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-y)\right]^2-\left[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x+y)\right]^2=2$$
$$(x-y)^2-(x+y)^2=4$$
$$-4xy=4$$
$$y=\frac{-1}{x}$$
Where is my error!  It's driving me nuts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation is $x^2 - y^2 = 2 $, not ${x'}^2 - {y'}^2 = 2 $. Write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $x'$ and $y'$. It should work. I think you actually applied the inverse rotation, with that misplaced substitution.

Comment: Interesting result that what I did was the inverse rotation!  Thanks for the help, I can see where I erred now.

Comment: @Lalaloopsy Here a nice thing to know: if you have the matrix of rotation with $\theta$s in it, to get its inverse, just put $- \theta$ everywhere you had $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

x2−y2=2 'opens' symetrically along Y-axis. Rotating this 45 deg. does give y=−1/x.

In other words you are rotating the wrong direction!